What is the meaning of @ and & in PennyLane?
What is the meaning of @ or & in PennyLane code like this one:
qml.expval(qml.PauliX(0) @ qml.PauliX(1))


The @ operator is syntactic sugar for the __matmul__ function in python. In the context you’re referring to, this operator has been overloaded to perform multiplication of Pauli operators. You can look at Pennylane’s repo if you want details of how exactly be operator is being defined but in essence, it is performing the product of Paulis in different qubits.
As for the & operator, you would need to provide context.

What's the point of using matmul, isn't tensor product more suitable?

matmul from numpy is not being used (if that’s what you mean). The idea here is that, in python, if you define a class and then add the dunder method __matmul__, everytime you use the symbol @ between two objects of that class, it will execute whatever is defined inside that method. In the case of pennylane, what gets executed is their proprietary qml.prod function. As I mentioned above, you can go to their repo and see how that function is implemented

Here’s the code: https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane/blob/master/pennylane/ops/op_math/prod.py
